# Using matrix columns create different vectors in r

Tags: r

The data is as follows:

```
myMatrix<- matrix(c(1:9),3,3)
res1 <- lsa::cosine(myMatrix[,1], myMatrix[,2])
res2 <- lsa::cosine(myMatrix[,2], myMatrix[,3])
res3 <- lsa::cosine(myMatrix[,1], myMatrix[,3])
```

I want to dynamically create res1, res2, and res3 without manually typing the dimensions as myMatrix[,1].

The matrix can be of nxm order as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to keep it in a `list`.  Create the `combn`inations of column sequence in a `list`, apply the `cosine` function and keep it in the `list`

```
lst1 <- combn(seq_len(ncol(myMatrix)), 2,  
    function(x) lsa::cosine(myMatrix[,x])[2], simplify = FALSE)
```

If we need to create those objects (not recommended), use `list2env` on a `named` list

```
names(lst1) <- paste0('res', seq_along(lst1))
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This worked just fine! So, now the first item in the list gives me a score b/w column 1 and 2 of the matrix. The second item gives the score b/w column 2 and 3..and so on. Now, the issue is that I want to count the instances where the score is greater than 0.50 in such a way that if Score(1-2)>0.50 and Score(2-3)>0.50 and Score(1-3)>0.50, then the last one shouldn't be counted due to transitivity. So the count should be as 2.